# Proof using induction Σ k+3 = n^2 / 2 + (7/2)n

Tags: induction

So I have the following problem

```
prove: Σ(n)(k+1) k+3 = n^2 / 2 + (7/2)n 
P(1) = 1 + 3 = 1^2 / 2 + 7 /2
P(1) = 4 = 4
So I assume it's true for n and attempt to prove it's true for n+1:
(n+1) + 3 = (n+1)^2 / 2 + (7/2)(n+1)
n+4 = (n^2 + 2n + 1) /2 + (7/2)(n+1)
```

and now I'm stuck. I have no idea how to make the functions equal. I can't really see a mistake either.

Comment: Do the distributions and stuff, then split off the pieces that were in the one for $n$ and set them aside for use with the hypothesis and see what happens.

Comment: can you use $\LaTeX$ please?

Comment: No idea how to use latex, looking it up.

Comment: You are stuck because "(n+1) + 3 = (n+1)^2 / 2 + (7/2)(n+1)" is not what the equation means for n or n+1. The equation for $n$ is $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (k + 3) = \frac{n^2 + 7n}{2}$$ You get to assume that is true. Now use that to prove the equation for $n+1$: $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} (k + 3) = \frac{(n+1)^2 + 7(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: By the way, a very useful trick for creating latex expressions: right-click on an expression you would like to copy (or just see how to get some symbol), and select "Show Math As > TEX commands". It gives you everything except for the beginning and ending \$s or \$$.

Comment: I still get stuck with a second degree polynomial equal to a first degree. To me there appears to be no way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (k + 3) = \frac{n^2 + 7n}{2}$ 
For the base case, $n=1$. $$1+3=\frac{8}{2}=4$$ 
Let us assume that it is true for some $n=p$, then $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^p (k + 3) = \frac{p^2 + 7p}{2}$$ 
Now it has to be true for all $n=p+1$, then $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p+1} (k + 3) = \frac{(p+1)^2 + 7(p+1)}{2}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^p(k+3)+p+4=\frac{(p+1)^2+7p+7}{2}$$
$$p+4=\frac{(p+1)^2+7p+7}{2}-\frac{p^2+7p}{2}$$
$$p+4=\frac{(2p+8}{2}$$
$$p+4=p+4$$
Which is true. Hence proved.

Comment: @JakeBurns, if you wrote in $\LaTeX$ then I could have shown you your mistake, sorry.